# Google App Engine - Java 8 and JSP Files: compilation error

Tags: eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine, java-8, jetty

I just configured my Eclipse Mars with JDK8 and Google Eclipse Plugin.
As reported by the [documentation itself](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download), the JDK8 is usable if the project compliance is set to JDK7, which I have done.

It seems that the project works fine if is limited to Servlet endpoints, but if there are any JSP files there is a problem starting the dev-server.

Here a simple guide on how to reproduce the problem.

- Create a new App Engine Maven Project (I used "`appengine-skeleton-archetype`" archetype)
- Create a new JSP file (inside the `webapp` folder) with a content of your choice
- In web.xml change the welcome-file to index.jsp
- Start the dev-server

The JSP file I made is very simple, is just template-created by Eclipse:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Here!
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to edit the `<welcome-file>` configuration you can simply invoke the JSP you made by url

If you have a configuration like mine (Eclipse with JDK8), starting the dev-server you should get something like this

```
giu 25, 2016 6:04:18 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFORMAZIONI: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\Nicola\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-sdk\1.9.38\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.38\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\Nicola\workspace_neon\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\test\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
giu 25, 2016 6:04:18 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFORMAZIONI: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
giu 25, 2016 6:04:19 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl setServerTimeZone
AVVERTENZA: Unable to set the TimeZone to UTC (this is expected if running on JDK 8)
giu 25, 2016 6:04:19 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFORMAZIONI: jetty-6.1.x
giu 25, 2016 6:04:21 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFORMAZIONI: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
giu 25, 2016 6:04:21 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService startHotDeployScanner
INFORMAZIONI: Full scan of the web app in place every 5s.
giu 25, 2016 6:04:21 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFORMAZIONI: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
giu 25, 2016 6:04:21 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFORMAZIONI: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
giu 25, 2016 6:04:21 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFORMAZIONI: Dev App Server is now running
giu 25, 2016 6:04:22 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
GRAVE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:206)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2187)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:429)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:84)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

giu 25, 2016 6:04:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
AVVERTENZA: /
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:84)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

The are 2 differents error, but it seems to be related to each other

```
 Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
```

and

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I did some research and found the problem related to JDK8 with TomCat7, but with App Engine the dev-server is based on Jetty, so the proposed solution are not usable

Because the main project works (html pages, java servlets, ...) the problem seems to be confined to jsp files

Comment: Someone seems to swallow interesting details of the ClassFormatException. That exception should contain the information about the offending class file and what problem was detected. Any chance you debug this to inspect the exception?

Comment: Note: this issue was fixed as of [Google Cloud SDK 131.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk), which I believe corresponds to the [AppEngine Java SDK 1.9.44](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/download).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problems (not exactly the above) and the only way I could resolve them was using jdk 7. So unless you are using java8 specific features, I recommend you try java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Not too surprising that doesn't work - that appengine environment is using jetty-6, which came out way before jdk8 existed :)

Here's a link to an open issue for google to upgrade to jetty-9: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9537

Jan

Answer (score 1):

Installing JDK7 next to JDK8 (for Eclipse the main JDK remains JDK8) and use it as Server Runtime solved the problem

[image]

To make it work the project class files to the JDK7 Server Runtime it is required to compile the project using JDK7 level compiler

Comment: Wow, a similar adjustment actually did the trick for me in Netbeans when running Tomcat server through it. I adjusted the Tomcat server in Netbeans to use JDK 1.7 instead of 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the underlying Jetty instance is bundled with an older version of the Eclipse Java Compiler (ECJ) that pre-dates Java 8.  This version of ECJ cannot read a Java8 JRE's class files.  Fortunately later versions of `ecj` are binary compatible, and so you can just find and replace the `ecj` jar with a more recent one.

The following steps worked for me. YMMV.

### For the Google Cloud SDK

`$ cd platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/tools/jsp
$ mv repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar OLD-repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar.OLD
$ cp ../../../jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.ecj-4.4.2.jar .`

### For the App Engine SDK

`$ cd lib/tools/jsp
$ mv repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar OLD-repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar.OLD
$ cp ../../../jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.ecj-4.4.2.jar .`

Comment: Is it necessary to rename `repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar`? I tried only adding the other `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.ecj-4.4.2.jar` and the server is working fine

Comment: I just tried again and it doesn't seem to matter.  It may be that the jars are sorted before being pulled in?

Comment: seems like i do have the same ecj jar file. but still getting same issue

Comment: @sparsh610 Please try with the latest [App Engine SDK for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download). I believe this issue has been fixed for a while.